# How to implement Container Transform with Material Motion on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I have **FirstPage**, where there is a FloatingActionButton. When user clicks on it, I need to show **SecondPage** (f.ex. via NavigationComponent). Complicity of this feature - is that I need is animate its previewing like on scheme below:

[image]

I know about Material Motion (https://m2.material.io/develop/android/theming/motion#container-transform) as it can animate containers but it works only for plain old Fragments and Views not for Compose. Is there any way to do similar on Compose ?

Comment: It appears to be "In Focus" on the roadmap for compose under the name "Shared element transitions" https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/compose-roadmap

Comment: @ElliotSknr, hello and thank you for an answer. Maybe you know - what does it mean "In Focus"? Maybe some estimates etc? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Unfortunately they haven't given a timeframe as far as I can see, the below is from their website: "In Focus items are being worked on soon and are likely to land in an upcoming stable release. Backlog items are planned but not likely to land soon."

Comment: Still in focus ...